# PDF Low Level - Center aligned text

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

How do I center align text on a PDF page inside the content object stream of a page.

Starting with this:

```
q 
  0 Tr 
  /Helv 12 Tf 
  BT 
    1 0 0 1 10 10 Tm 
    (Hello)Tj
  ET
  BT 
    1 0 0 1 90 10 Tm 
   (World)Tj
  ET
Q
```

Which is an absolute positioning of the text, I'd like to write 1 line at a time, starting from 1/3 of the way down the page (say y 600) and write the text center aligned.

So it would look like:

```
                                      Hello
                                      World
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no center command. You will need to work it out manually

Comment: Although as you have the page width and the width of all the text, it should not be too complex to work out the required values...

Comment: The text is dynamic. I ended up doing it as an image with GD, converted to JBIG2. It was easier, and no need to embed to font.